# creating a new variables with missing values

Tags: r, if-statement

Here is some sample data.

```
vv  var1    var2
1   a   1/1/2010
1   c   1/3/2010
2   d   1/6/2010
3   a   1/8/2010
3   c   1/9/2010
4   a   1/10/2010
4   b   1/11/2010
5   d   1/13/2010
6   a   1/16/2010
6   b   1/17/2010
7   a   1/19/2010
7   b   1/20/2010
8   d   1/22/2010
9   a   1/25/2010
9   c   1/27/2010
```

I am trying to create new variables, populated by responses from other variables.  I thought this to be easy enough.  For example, I tried something like below.

```
data$new1[data$var1=="a"]<-data$var2
#or
data$new1[data$var1=="b" | data$var1=="c"]<-data$var2
```

I get the error `number of items to replace is not of replacement length`.  In my data, not every `var1=="a"` has a `var2` value, so I am not sure why r is not just assigning NA's for missing values, which is something that I am okay with (rather prefer it actually).  Basically, I want r to give `new1` NA values for any `var1!="a"`.

I also tried

```
if (data$var1=="a") {data$new1<-data$var2} else {data$new1<-"NA"}
```

but I get the error `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`.

Now, I think I can subset my data to only have data with `var1=="a"`, and then assign my values, and then just merge back into the main data set with the `all=T` option to get the NA's imputed, but I really want to avoid doing this.

I am not really sure what the problem is.  Any advice greatly appreciated.  Cheers.

Output from methods below for running the code:

```
data$new1 <- ifelse(data$var1 %in% c("b","c"),data$var2,NA)

       vv var1      var2 new1
    1   1    a  1/1/2010   NA
    2   1    c  1/3/2010   12
    3   2    d  1/6/2010   NA
    4   3    a  1/8/2010   NA
    5   3    c  1/9/2010   15
    6   4    a 1/10/2010   NA
    7   4    b 1/11/2010    3
    8   5    d 1/13/2010   NA
    9   6    a 1/16/2010   NA
    10  6    b 1/17/2010    6
    11  7    a 1/19/2010   NA
    12  7    b 1/20/2010    8
    13  8    d 1/22/2010   NA
    14  9    a 1/25/2010   NA
    15  9    c 1/27/2010   11
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add reproducible sample for good people here to help you. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you haven't given sample data, this code is untested

```
data$new1 <- rep(NA, nrow(data))
data$new1[data$var1=="A"] <- data$var2[data$var1=="A"]
```

Key here is to have same subsetting paramter (`data$var1=="A"`) for both `data$new1` and `data$var2`.

The advantage of this method, is that subsetting doesn't have to be just equality but any logical expression.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the advice.  I got your way to work, however, I am losing the dates and just getting numbers for new1.

Comment: @user27008 can you paste output of `dput(data)` in your question?

Comment: Seems like `Var2` is a factor not `date` or `character`

Comment: @user27008 try `data$Var2 <- as.character(data.Var2)` before running above code in answer

Comment: Sorry, wont let me upvote the answer says I need 15 rep.  I did select it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I think you want to use `ifelse` and `%in%` to perform this task:

```
data$new1 <- ifelse(data$var1 %in% c("A","B"),data$var2,NA)
```

What you have performed is subsetting, which will often return something smaller, hence the warnings you are getting.

Comment: where will data$new1 be initially populated from?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for advice.  I am getting the error `unexpected 'in' in data$new1 <- ifelse(data$var1 %in%`.

Comment: @user27008 I'm not sure why that is happening. Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: I got your code to work for the example.  My data is just troublesome I guess.  But I am losing the dates and just getting numbers as values for new1.